# In Task Scheduler what is the difference between "at logon" and "at startup"?

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

They both sound synonymous.
Do programs "at startup" run before the programs "at logon"?
Or do they still run if you don't logon?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"At startup" tasks run when the computer starts, whether anyone ever logs on or not.

"At log on" tasks run when a specific user or any user logs on, depending on how you set it.

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748841.aspx

Comment: Sorry: In general this is not correct. If you create a "At startup" task with the wizard it will have the same behaviour to start a task "at logon". Even if you would check the button "Independend of user logon" it won't start at system startup time if you have not includes the user in the security rules for batchjobs. Only in this case you will really have a "at startup" execution. (and some programms will resist to start in this mode)